# Salvar hora atual e hora final no banco sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto sobre automação residencial e no momento ao clicar no botão LIGAR se realizaria as seguintes funcionalidades: iniciar dispositivo, iniciar cronometro, salvar hora atual e enviar para o banco de dados.

Ao clicar no botão Desligar, se desligaria o dispositivo, cronometro seria zerado, seria salvo hora atual de desligamento do dispositivo e seria enviado para o banco.

Ocorre que ao tentar salvar a hora atual quando clica em LIGAR apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
05-30 12:31:25.874    2192-2192/com.example.jhow.tecnumautomao E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1299) abort at 5 in [INSERT INTO contacts(tempoInicial) VALUES (?)]: NOT NULL constraint failed: contacts.name
05-30 12:31:25.895    2192-2192/com.example.jhow.tecnumautomao E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting tempoInicial=12:31:25
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: contacts.name (code 1299)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
            at com.example.jhow.tecnumautomao.Persistencia.PessoaDAO.dadosTimeInicial(PessoaDAO.java:158)
            at com.example.jhow.tecnumautomao.lampada_quarto$1.onClick(lampada_quarto.java:77)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Segue também método que salva hora no banco:

TABELA DA CLASSE DBSQLITE:

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String TABLE_CREATE =

            "CREATE TABLE " + Pessoa.TABLE_NAME  + "("
            + Pessoa.COLUNA_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
            + Pessoa.COLUNA_NOME + " TEXT, "
            + Pessoa.COLUNA_UNAME + " TEXT, "
            + Pessoa.COLUNA_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + Pessoa.COLUNA_PASS + " TEXT, "
            + Pessoa.COLUNA_TIME_INICIAL + " TEXT, "
            + Pessoa.COLUNA_TIME_FINAL + " TEXT "
            + Pessoa.COLUNA_SENHA1 + " TEXT, "
            + Pessoa.COLUNA_SENHA2 + " TEXT )";

    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    this.db = db;


}
```

METODOS PARA SALVAR O TEMPO

```
public void dadosTimeInicial(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbsqLite.getWritableDatabase();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat_hora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");


    Date data = new Date();
    Calendar  cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(data);
    Date data_atual = cal.getTime();

    String hora_atual = dateFormat_hora.format(data_atual);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Pessoa.COLUNA_TIME_INICIAL, hora_atual);

    db.insert(Pessoa.TABLE_NAME, null , values );
    db.close();
}

 public void dadosTimeFinal (){


    SQLiteDatabase db = dbsqLite.getWritableDatabase();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat_hora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");


    Date data = new Date();
    Calendar  cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(data);
    Date data_atual = cal.getTime();

    String hora_atual = dateFormat_hora.format(data_atual);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Pessoa.COLUNA_TIME_FINAL, hora_atual);

    db.insert(Pessoa.TABLE_NAME, null , values );
    db.close();
```

Comment: Quando você criou a tabela "contacts" pela primeira vez, por acaso o campo "name" era originalmente NOT NULL e depois você modificou para NULL (como está agora no código que você postou)?

Comment: OLá não não realizei essa modificação que você mencionou, o erro que esta dando é causado pelo campo "name " ? mas como esse trecho de codigo não faz modificação no mesmo ?

Comment: É porque se esse campo fosse originalmente NOT NULL quando criou o banco, ele iria dar o erro, pois você está inserindo apenas dados de data e os demais nulos. E às vezes um erro comum quando se implementa banco de dados no Android e fazemos uma alteração na estrutura do banco no onCreate do Helper, esquecemos de reinstalar o app ou então implementar as alterações na rotina onUpgrade, e com isso não vemos as alterações do banco no app, que no seu caso poderia ser a coluna name ainda como NOT NULL reclamando que se está tentando inserir um valor nulo nela (que é o que o erro está dizendo).

Comment: no caso se esse for o problema é possivel eu alterar a coluna "name" de NOT NULL para NULL ? como eu faria essa modificação no sqlite do android ?

Comment: Pelo código que você postou ela já está como NULL, não deveria estar dando esse erro se o banco foi criado assim desde o início. Só por curiosidade, tenta escrever algum valor nessa coluna, mesmo que uma string vazia, além da data, só pra ver se o erro some ou muda.